# How to install "libqt5webview5-dev" on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, qt5

I'm not an expert, I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, and I'm trying to install Stremio by following this tutorial "https://github.com/Stremio/stremio-shell/blob/master/DEBIAN.md" from source codes.

So in order to make it work, I have to install the "libqt5webview5-dev" package, but unfortunately I get the error "Unable to locate package libqt5webview5-dev". *(sorry the following terminal outputs are in Fench)*

```
$sudo apt-get install -y libqt5webview5
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances       
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
E: Impossible de trouver le paquet libqt5webview5
```

I tried to add the "universe" repository but it was already enabled.

```
$sudo add-apt-repository universe
Le composant de distribution « universe » est déjà activé pour toutes les sources.
```

Maybe my distribution is too old ? Can you help me ?

Thanks!

Comment: according to online package search available starting from ubuntu bionic.

Comment: ok, that's what I was afraid of ...

Comment: thank you for your response !

Answer (score 0):

This may be possible. It doesn't seem to have many dependencies. We're going to pull it from the 18.04 repo and install it with apt.

```
sudo apt update
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/q/qtwebview-opensource-src/libqt5webview5-dev_5.9.5-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./libqt5webview5-dev_5.9.5-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

`apt-cache showpkg libqt5webview5-dev` indicates the following dependencies must be met:

> 5.9.5-0ubuntu1 - libqt5webview5 (5 5.9.5-0ubuntu1) qtbase5-dev (0 (null)) qtdeclarative5-dev (0 (null)) libqt5webview5-dev:i386 (35
> 5.9.5-0ubuntu1) libqt5webview5-dev:i386 (38 5.9.5-0ubuntu1)

You might already have some/all of those installed, I have no idea because I haven't used `16.04` in a long time. They *can* also be installed in a similar manner.

**NOTE:** I have absolutely no idea if this will make your system unstable. It doesn't *look* all that invasive, but it may cause issues. Fortunately, you can undo all of this, but I highly recommend you backup your system before you attempt this.

Addendum: If you're curious as to how I got the address for wget, it's pretty simple.

1. Go to [pkgs.org](https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/).
2. Find your package with the search function.
3. Scroll down and find the actual address for the .deb file.

With some work, you *can* install most anything. It's just not always a good idea.

Comment: Wow thanks for this precise and clear response ! Actually, this was one of my attempt, so I tried to "manually" installed the package but in some way I didn't manage to succeed... and yes, I also saw that this is not recommended, but I will try again as you suggest to do, and let you know if it works ! :)

Comment: It could be dependencies all-the-way down, but it doesn't look too bad. When you hit an unmet dependency, you'll have to look it up and install it. I'm also reminded of, "Just because you can doesn't mean you should."